# react hot loader not updating frontend

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm not sure why my front end isn't running in hot mode. I am trying to decouple the front end and backend as much as possible. The only thing that connects the two is that I use django's `webpack_loader` app to load the `webpack` build to load into a template (`index.html`).

My backend is in Django and it is currently running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.

My frontend is hosted on `localhost:8080`

My devServer for hot mode is on `0.0.0.0:8080`

I tried changing a bit of my front end and saving it to see what would happen and nothing on the front end has been updated. In my developer tools I see this:

```
[HMR] Update check failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8000/static/js/main.js:44:33)
```

Here are my npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch-client": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --verbose --colors --display-error-details --config webpack.watch.js && node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config webpack.watch.js",
    "watch": "npm run watch-client"
  },
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './app/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/js/',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    debug: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'jsx-loader' },
            { test: /\.es6$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
            { test: /\.less$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")},
            { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', {
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js'),
    ]
};
```

webpack.watch.js:

```
var Webpack = require("webpack");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var config = require("./webpack.config.js");
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

var port = process.env.WEBPACK_PORT || 8080;
var host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';

// add hot loader
config.entry.unshift(
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://" + host + ":" + port,
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server"   // only prevents reload on syntax errors
);

config.plugins = [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", {
        allChunks: true
    }),
    new Webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})
];

config.module.loaders = [
    { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
    { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'jsx-loader' },
    { test: /\.es6$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
    { test: /\.less$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")},
    { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
];

// dev server for react hot loader
config.devServer = {
    publicPath:  "/js/",
    filename: 'main.js',
    contentBase: "./public",
    hot:         true,
    inline:      true,
    lazy:        false,
    quiet:       true,
    noInfo:      true,
    headers:     {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
    stats:       {colors: true},
    host:        "0.0.0.0",
    port:        port
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: where are you using react-hot-loader?

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem